# Android : Setting a sound from SD card as Ringtone

Tags: android, path, audio, uri, ringtone

I am trying to set a ringtone from a sound I saved onto the SD card from within my app.  After going through every post I could find on this, I believe I am close, and just not defining the URI's right.

```
       File ringPath = new File(path, filename);

       ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
       values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, ringPath.getAbsolutePath());
       values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "temptitle");
       values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, ringPath.length());
       values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/ogg");
       values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "tempartist");
       values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);

       uri = Uri.fromFile(ringPath);
       RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(this, RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, uri);
```

Typically the URI is defined more like :

```
Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(ringPath.getAbsolutePath());
Uri newUri = main.getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);
```

But I didn't quite see the point in all of that, and it gave me rather nasty errors (Not that they were likely any worse than my current one).  I am sure that is the required way to do it, but the uri in my code actually returns the proper path (And the other doesn't, granted likely due to my misuse), so I don't see why it wouldn't work.  Though to be honest I don't see the point in having to using URI's for this anyway, rather than specifying the paths.

If anybody could give me a little explanation, or link me somewhere that would, so I could really comprehend this and get around this issue I'd be very grateful.

Comment: What permissions have you given your application? You have to make sure that your app has permission to access the SD card.

Comment: I've given the permissions to write to the external storage, and I know it is set properly since I can save the sound onto the SD card.  I don't believe there are any permissions required to READ from the card, and I did just double check to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is not getting path. So I would recommend you to start with check if your file is really exists after this line

```
 File ringPath = new File(path, filename);
```

Use code:

```
boolean b=ringPath.exists();
```

If it returns true than you can able to get uri from it. Then after I think no error I can see in your code.

Comment: I used that check previously to make sure it was, but I did it again and yes, it does return true.  After tinkering for a while, the sound now does show up in the ringtones list and works, but it somehow fails when it tries to set it as the ringtone the first time when it should.  It replaces it with some default ring instead.  Worst case scenario I could use it like that, but I would prefer it to fully set the ringtone when the user asks it to.

Answer (score 0):

Shut off phone debugging by going into Menu->Settings->Applications->Development  Then uncheck the box.  Good to go.